# How to create a dropdown list on excel that filters a table?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I have a table with the following headings on `Sheet 1`:

> List of Areas-----List of Defects

And a table like the following on `Sheet 2`:

> Area-----Defect-----Cause-----etcetera

I want to create a dropdown list on `Sheet 2` for defects that refers to the table on `Sheet 1` and shows only the defects for the respective area.

The problem is that there are a lot of areas and each area has many defects, so for example Area A may appear 10 times on the first table.

What have I already tried?

1. Creating a sepearate table for every Area, however there are too many areas and it is not worth it
2. Creating a named range, however, new defect will be constantly included on the first table
3. I also tried the `=OFFSET(INDEX(Table1;MATCH(F5;Table1[List of Areas];0));;1;COUNTIF(Table1[List of Areas];F5))` combined with the indirect command.
   However given that the tables are in diferent sheets i cannot acces them.

How can I fix this?